# Photo Competition 2021-07-19: Inspired by Photography Stack Exchange

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Inspired by Photography Stack Exchange

Craft a picture that was inspired by a question, answer, or comment here. Include a link to the inspiration (and a sentence or two about how you got from the original question to your photo).

This theme was suggested by user2910.

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/125387/photo-competition-2021-07-19-inspired-by-photography-stack-exchange?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on July 19, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Comment: Seriously, this is the least inspiring theme yet.

Comment: Maybe we could switch to the next theme?

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 Interesting idea. I never thought about this scenario occurring. I opened a Meta-PSE question: [What happens when there are no submissions for PotW contest?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7165/11924)

Comment: @EricS I'm bummed it hasn't produced anything. I was hoping that it would. But I suppose it kinda makes sense. =/

Comment: I guarantee if you used the cat theme there would be at least a dozen entries. Maybe two dozen. This theme is too meta.

Comment: @EricS asking for cat pics on the internet is like drinking straight from the firehose. https://i.imgur.com/w34EEXb.gif

Comment: I know, but I have a particular cat picture that I love. It could have worked for street photography, but I was out of town during that theme.

Comment: @EricS Being a grumpy git I can never see the (photographic) point in cat pictures. I'm more of a duck billed platipus person! :-P

Comment: There has been a general downward trend since it went to community wiki. Maybe people *do* like to win things, even if it's only invisible interweb points;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I've noticed that as well. I don't think in this case that is the reason for a lack of entries. It seems to me (and I could be completely off kilter) that the lack of submissions to this theme is because most of the active participants here answer questions, rather than ask them. Most questions here are asked by users who don't stick around very long. They get the answer(s) they need to do what they want and then they stop participating. Ergo, those most likely to have been inspired by questions/answers here are not active participants.